# Making space between two tables

Tags: plotting, output-formatting

[image]How can we make space between two tables arranged in the columns and each table contains four columns? Kindy let me know? I want this kind of table. Kindly let me know. I want it in latex?

Comment: Are you sure it is a Mathematica question?

Answer (score 4):

TableForm has several options to decorate a tabular view nicely, but in your case there's enough complexity to use Grid, and actually nested Grids might be simplest.

First some sample data:

```
data1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 3}];
data2 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 3}];
headings1 = {"A", "B", "C"};
headings2 = {"x", "y", "z"};
title1 = "first title";
title2 = "second title";
```

Now each smaller grid:

```
table1 =
  Grid[
    FlattenAt[{{title1, SpanFromLeft}, headings1, data1}, 3],
    Dividers -> {False, {False, True, True, {False}}},
    Spacings -> {2, .5},
    Alignment -> {".", Center, {{1, 2}, {1, 3}} -> Left},
    Background -> LightBrown];
table2 =
  Grid[
    FlattenAt[{{title2, SpanFromLeft}, headings2, data2}, 3],
    Dividers -> {False, {False, True, True, {False}}},
    Spacings -> {2, .5},
    Alignment -> {".", Center, {{1, 2}, {1, 3}} -> Left},
    Background -> LightGreen];
```

The background options are just to help visualize these effects.

Now combine them:

```
mainTable =
  Grid[
  {{table1, table2}},
  Spacings -> {3, 1},
  Dividers -> {None, {True, {False}, True}},
  Background -> Yellow]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

it is hard to understand what you are asking. It would be better to sketch by hand what you meant and post an image.

But may be you meant you want 2 matrices next to each others with more horizontal space between them? For that use the [Spacer](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Spacer.html) command

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
tbl1 = Table[n + m, {m, 3}, {n, 4}]
tbl2 = Table[n*m, {m, 3}, {n, 4}]
Grid[{{MatrixForm@tbl1, Spacer[40], MatrixForm@tbl2}}, Frame -> True]
```

If you meant on top of each others, then

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Column[{MatrixForm@tbl1, Spacer[40], MatrixForm@tbl2}, Frame -> True]
```